# Exporting Emails from Outlook Folders into Excel. Coding issue

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm working on the following code and I'm trying to get it to add emails from two different folders in Outlook but I'm obviously missing something because it won't work. What happens is when I run the code it pulls all the emails from the "PolicyCenter" folder but not the "Apex" folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
Sub VBA_Export_Outlook_Emails_To_Excel()
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String

MailBoxName = "Mailbox, PL-SYSTEM-OUTAGES"

Pst_Folder_Name = "Apex"
Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter"

    For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
    If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
    For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
        If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
            Set Folder = sFolders
            GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        End If
    Next sFolders
Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
 If Folder.Name = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo End_Lbl1:
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6) = "Body"

oRow = 1
For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count

    If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
       oRow = oRow + 1
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    End If
Next iRow
MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
Set Folder = Nothing
Set sFolders = Nothing

End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

Thanks!!
-D

Comment: You set `Pst_Folder_Name = "Apex"` then in the next line of code overwrite it with `Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter"`. So the code never runs for "Apex".

Comment: Okay so is there a way to get it so it will copy the contents of both folders? I'm having some issues figuring it out.

Comment: would putting the "new folder name" between the two next statements do it?     Next sFolders 
Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter" Next Folder

Comment: @Deke There are several ways to run on both folders. (a) Probably easiest: run the program once for with `Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter"` then run a second time with `Pst_Folder_Name = "Apex"`; (b) Create an array `Dim FolderNames(1 to 2) as String`, fill the array with the 2 folder names, and put the "workhorse" part of your code in a `For` loop; (c) Have your macro take an argument `Sub VBA_Export_Outlook_Emails_To_Excel(FolderName as String)` then call it twice from another subroutine

Comment: I had actually tried to setup a macro that would just run all my reports by using `Call Module1.VBA_Export_Outlook_Emails_To_Excel ` and doing this from Modules 1 - 19 (all my reports) but the problem is they keep overwriting each other as they all start on A2... if I could get it so they ran on the next available line that would solve my problem. Any idea how to make that work?

Comment: @Xidgel I'm not sure I quite understand. I'm very new to coding and teaching myself by looking up bits of code and stringing them together with a lot of trial and error. Could you elaborate a little in more?

Comment: @Deke The easiest way to avoid the overwriting problem is run the first mail folder then copy and paste the results to a safe spot. Repeat for the remaining folders. If you want something more automated your code needs to detect the last row; instead of `oRow = 1` you need something like `oRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1`

Comment: @Xidgel I tried to use ` ThisWorkBook.ListObjects(Tabel1).UsedRange.Rows.Count +1 ` but it doesn't seem to work. Says "Object doesn't support this property or Method". Any suggestions? I just need this to start on empty row in my table.

Answer (score 0):

would putting the "new folder name" between the two next statements do it?

```
Next sFolders
Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter"
Next Folder
```

Did this to show what I meant...

Comment: So you mean adding it in the following `Pst_Folder_Name = "Apex" For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then Set Folder = sFolders GoTo Label_Folder_Found End If Next sFolders Next Folder Pst_Folder_Name = "PolicyCenter" Next sFolders Next Folder ` (Sorry can't seem to get this to show properly) But putting here doesn't seem to work. Still only imports one folders emails

Comment: I meant after the next sFolders but before the next Folder

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't seem to work. Can't seem to figure out how to get this to pull from multiple folders no matter what I do. Any other ideas??? I've been trying everything I can think of (limited by what I know which isn't alot) for the last 2 days. My eyes are going to fall out of my head. I just need to get this to either pull all emails from multiple mailboxes or run all my pre existing modules (each one setup to pull emails from one specific box) and enter them on a sheet in the next available line without writing over each other. I do really appreciate the help so far.

Comment: go with @xidgel's solution A where you run the program with the first folder name then again with the second folder name